# Ruby gems issue with upgrading

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I run `rails generate controller welcome index` 
I got the warning 
`You're using Rubygems 2.0.14 with Spring. Upgrade to at least Rubygems 2.1.0 and run gem pristine --all`

I updated gem --system and also added paths into ~/.bashrc, but still same result, is there any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I had an older Ruby version 2.0 from the past, so it made apache confuse. I could either explicitly telling apache to use which directory, or use RVM (Ruby Version Manager) which do all jobs. Just need to go through these steps:

Install RVM:

```
rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles
```

Then tell which version you tend to use:

```
rvm use 2.2.0
```

Update gems

```
gem install rails
```

Now ready to go!

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Gemfile.lock and change your version of Ruby. That might do it.

What Ruby manager are you using?